# Laravel - summing price with where method for paying method

Tags: php, laravel, sum

So right now I'm working on project that needs price summing on each payment method, for example if somebody is paying with cash it needs to sum total price for every cash payment. Here is my code

This is my `home.blade.php` :

```
@extends('layouts.theme')

@section('content')
    <style>
        body{
            margin: 0;
            background-color: #EBEBEB;
        }
    </style>
    <div class="mainl">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="columna">



                <h1>{{ Auth::user()->name }}</h1>
                <hr>
            </div>

            <div class="columns">
                <a href="{{ route('logout') }}" id="logout"
                onclick="event.preventDefault();
                        document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
                    {{ __('LOGOUT') }}
                </a>

                <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
                    @csrf
                </form>

            </div>
        </div>
        </br></br></br>

        @if(count($posts)> 0)
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>BR.KESICE</th>
                    <th>IME I PREZIME</th>
                    <th>BR.TELEFONA</th>
                    <th>POSAO</th>
                    <th>CIJENA</th>
                    <th>PLACANJE</th>
                    <th>POPUST</th>
                    <th>DATUM PREUZ.</th>
                    <th>DATUM IZDAV.</th>
                    <th>SMJENA</th>
                    <th>RADNIK</th>
                    <th>STATUS</th>
                    <th>IZMIJENI</th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($posts as $post)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{$post->br_kesice}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->ime}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->br_telefona}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->posao}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->cijena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->placanje}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->popust}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->datum_preuz}}</td>
                    @if($post->status == 1)
                        <td>/</td>
                    @else
                        <td>{{$post->datum_izdav}}</td>
                    @endif
                    <td>{{$post->smjena}}</td>
                    <td>{{$post->radnik}}</td>
                    <td>
                        @if($post->status == 0)
                        <span class="label label-primary" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 1)
                        <span class="label label-success" id="statusaktivan">Aktivan</span>
                        @elseif($post->status == 2)
                        <span class="label label-danger" id="statusdeaktivan">Rejected</span>
                        @else
                        <span class="label label-info" id="statusdeaktivan">Deaktivan</span>
                        @endif
                    </td>
                    @if($post->status == 3)

                    @else
                    <td><a href="posts/{{$post->id}}/edit" class="edit"><i class="far fa-edit"></i></a></td>
                    @endif

                </tr>

                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
                <tr>
                    <th>UKUPAN IZNOS:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->sum('cijena') }}&euro;</th>
                    <th>KARTICA:&nbsp;&nbsp;{{ Auth::user()->posts->where('placanje', 'Kartica')->where('created_at','=',$date)->sum('cijena')}}&euro;</th>
                </tr>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
        <br><br>
        {{ $posts->links() }}
        @else
            <p>Trenutno nema unosa.</p>
        @endif
    </div>
@endsection
```

In this `home.blade.php` I put `where('created_at','=',$date)`
from my HomeController but it's not working. In my homepage it only shows posts made today. And this is how I did it in my
`HomeController.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;
use App\Post;
use DB;
use Auth;
use Carbon\Carbon;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */

     public function index()
    {
        $date = new Carbon(request('date'));

        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id())
                ->whereDate('created_at','=',$date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(30); //add {{ $posts->links() }} if paginate is enabled
        return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
    }
}
```

So all I need is when manager create post and type in method of payment for example 'Kartica', in my homepage it table footer it needs to sum total payment of all posts MADE TODAY and all price for 'Kartica' payment method also from TODAY. If anyone have idea please let me know, thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`created_at` field use `YYYY-MM-DD HH:II:SS` format so you have to filter by date not by datetime.
You can do something like this:

```
public function index()
{
    $date = new Carbon(request($date))->format("Y-m-d");

    ...
    ->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?', $date)
    ...
}
```

`whereRaw` method can be used to inject a raw where clause into your query.

Comment: Yes but the problem is when I add ```->format("Y-m-d");``` it returns me syntax error '->' .. what should I do ?

Comment: Syntax error means that there is an error with PHP, not with Laravel. Could you paste your code and your syntax error here in the comments?

Comment: here is my code for ```HomeController``` index function: 
```
     public function index()
    {
        $date = new Carbon(request('date'))->format("Y-m-d");
        
        $posts = Post::where('user_id', Auth::id(1))
                ->whereRaw('DATE(created_at) = ?', $date)
                ->orderBy('created_at', 'DESC')
                ->paginate(30); //add {{ $posts->links() }} if paginate is enabled
        return view('home', compact('date', $date))->with('posts', $posts);
    }```

Comment: and it throws me this: ```"syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)"``` for that ```->format("Y-m-d");```

Comment: Try this command to create a new date with Carbon: 
$date = Carbon::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "2019-08-12")->format("Y-m-d");
If you are using a different format edit it in the createFromFormat argument

Comment: Okay it's everything working just fine now! Thank you Sir!